# How I can specify number of top rows in LINQ to XML?

Tags: linq-to-xml

in LINQ to SQL I can say var ......Take(50);
Now I have this LINQ2XML code:

```
                    XElement xml = new XElement("Materials",
                    from material in _db.MTIs
                    where material.MTName.ToString().Contains(comparer)
                    select new XElement("Material",
                              new XElement("MTID", material.MTID),
                              new XElement("MTName", material.MTName),
                              new XElement("ComputerNO", material.ComputerNO),
                              new XElement("ModelNO", material.ModelNO),
                              new XElement("Whole", material.Whole)));
```

and I want to get the top 50 rows of matched results only how I can perform such thing?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
                XElement xml = new XElement("Materials",
                _db.MTIs.Where(material => material.MTName.ToString().Contains(comparer))
                .Take(50)
                .Select(material =>
                    new XElement("Material",
                          new XElement("MTID", material.MTID),
                          new XElement("MTName", material.MTName),
                          new XElement("ComputerNO", material.ComputerNO),
                          new XElement("ModelNO", material.ModelNO),
                          new XElement("Whole", material.Whole))));
```